# Perl how to read HTML bottom to top

Tags: regex, perl

So I have a body of HTML setup like so in Perl:

```
$html = "<html>
<p>This is <div>some</div> text</p>
<br><br>
<p>This is <div>second</div> line text</p>
<br><br>
<p>This is <div>third</div> line text</p>
</html>";
```

By default when I use my perl script (to match), it read the HTML top to bottom.

Here is the "matching" part of my perl script:

```
my ($cropped_data) = ($html =~ /div[^>]*>([^<]+)/);
# $cropped_data will return 'some'
```

Though my question is, how can I read the script "bottom to top" so that the first "div" that it encounters would be the div enclosing the word "third" rather then "some".

Note: I am not permitted to edit the HTML in this situation.

Comment: Are you permitted to modify the `$html` *variable* **in memory**?

Comment: You can add a `.*` at the start of the expression (combined with the 's' dot-matches-all modifier) to force the regex engine to begin backtracking from the end of the string like so: `$html =~ /.*<div[^>]*>([^<]+)/s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that reverses the lines of the `$html` variable.

```
$html = "<html>
<p>This is <div>some</div> text</p>
<br><br>
<p>This is <div>second</div> line text</p>
<br><br>
<p>This is <div>third</div> line text</p>
</html>";

$html = join ("\n",reverse(split /\n/, $html));
my ($cropped_data) = ($html =~ /div[^>]*>([^<]+)/);
print $cropped_data
```

Output:

```
third
```